# How do I start Steam without it automatically logging in?

Tags: steam

When I start Steam it automatically logs into my account.

I want it setup so that when Steam starts next time, it will ask me for my credentials.

I know how to do this the normal way (logging into my account, going into settings) but I want to make this change without being logged into my account, or at least not being visible as logged in.

Answer (score 4):

IF you want to stop Steam from automagically logging you in, edit

```
\Steam\config\SteamAppData.vdf
```

and delete everything that is in there.

This will make Steam ask you for your username and password on the next launch.

Comment: Do you need to edit the file every time?

Comment: No, only 1 time if you want to stop Steam from logging in without actually logging in. No clue why this is asked so often, but okay. After that I suggest you use the "Do not store my credentials on this pc" setting.

Answer (score 0):

If Steam can't connect to the server, it will ask you if you want to start in Offline Mode. From there, you can select "change user", and then in the login dialog, uncheck the option to save your password.

In order to prevent Steam from connecting to the server when you launch it, you can first either 1) disconnect your computer from the network and thus the internet, or 2) use a firewall (such as the one included in your OS) to block outgoing connections from the client.

... However, user28015's method of deleting the .vdf file is quicker and easier.